# dotnet framework 4.5 dll on dotnet framework runtime v2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022

we have a legacy application developed in .net 2.0 that is running on target framework v2.0 in production.
Now,

- Cloned the application into vs 2022, did some code fixes, new dlls are created.
- Build solution in Release mode.
- Copied the new DLL into production.

I get the error when browse the application:
**Could not load file or assembly - or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. **

Is my approach wrong? Can I access dll created on higher version on lower version dotnet?
If no, what is the solution to my problem?

Comment: If you are OK with running on Windows 10 (not 11), a Fx2.0 app will run perfectly well on Fx3.51 which is considered a component of Win 10. Other than that, look at `FusLogVw.exe` as a tool that may help you find out what's not loading

Comment: See following : https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-net-framework-2-windows-8/

Comment: It's time to upgrade. Really, it's time. You put yourself and your customers at risk by running such obsolete software.

Comment: @DavidL, yes the upgrade is under way! Still in analysis mode. But needed some urgent fixes unfortunately.

Comment: @David unfortunately it is too early to say .NET Framework 3.5 is "obsolete". At least for now, this product is fully supported by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework, different from .NET Framework 4.x support policies.

Comment: @LexLi the OP specifically said .net framework 2.0 runtime. There is nothing in their question that says they’re changing the runtime.

Comment: @DavidL There isn't a .NET Framework 2.0 runtime ever since Windows Vista and .NET Framework 3.0. Today even if you compile against .NET Framework 2.0 API profile, the final assemblies are running on .NET Framework 3.5(.1). Microsoft pushed that via Windows Update and all supported Windows releases today enforce the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by your actions in "Cloned the application into vs 2022, did some code fixes, new dlls are created".

Recent VS releases usually prompt you to upgrade the project to latest .NET Framework releases (4.x), but in your situation you cannot.

Please go to project properties and change target framework back to .NET Framework 2.0.

People know for more than a decade that .NET Framework 2.0-3.5.1 cannot consume .NET Framework 4.x assemblies, and you should learn that too.

Comment: Yes, thats the first think I wanted to do "not upgrade while clonning", however now I need to install .NET Framework 2.0 on the new dev box as well now if there is no way forward.

Comment: However, .net 4, or even 4.8 should work fine, so that's what I would choose for the project. We always been able to "go forward" here, and I don't see why for example you can't choose .net 4.8 for the build process - it should work just fine.

Comment: @SangeethaM You must understand that many are stuck on .NET Framework 2.0/3.5 like you. Otherwise, Microsoft wouldn’t have set the support policies in such a generous way.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal .NET Framework 4.x has lots of breaking changes, so unless the app owner has all the source code (including dependencies) and know how to upgrade properly, they can be blocked in many cases. Something working for you does not apply to all others.

Comment: Fair point  -- yes I am assuming user has all source code. and a jump from say .net 4.0 to say 4.8 tends to be a "non issue". But a jump from 2.0? yes that needs some love and care, and some testing, and a good case that just a flip of .net framework to 4.x could and would often require some work. It much depends on how the existing application was cobbled to together.